# Collaboration tools recommendations like Slack

Tags: devsecops, slack

I started my graduation internship two weeks ago. My assignment is to look for a Slack alternative that'll be able to deploy on-premise. A lot of things need to be automated. I already did some research and found some interesting platforms like Mattermost, Zulip, Rocket.chat.

I was wondering if someone has any recommendations that really worth diving into? Also would like your extensive arguments about topics like user interface, integrations/webhooks/bots, security, scalability and so on.

Comment: Bij het deployen en implementeren komen er DevOps zaken bij kijken.. Dus het lijkt me niet heel ver weg van DevOps. Heb je een suggestie voor een andere community? @Pierre.Vriens

Answer (score 1):

TBH,

I would question the reason for it to be on-premise, since nowadays the trend is to look for SaaS solutions (so, nothing to maintain from an IT / Ops point of view).

Slack has a free plan as long as your team is not concerned about message retention or multi-calls/video.

I don't see the reason to have yet another piece of software to be installed/configured/maintained/patched/secured etc
when there are so many players out there which lift all of this out (for a price, of course), so if this is a case of "*my boss doesn't want it to be on the cloud/not under his control*" or b***shit like that, I would question the real need for it to be on-prem.

Even the old Skype4Business (therefore, Microsoft) dropped its on-prem installation in favour of Teams through Office365...

Again, my thought.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).